# How to redirect URL without changing URL in user's browser

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to redirect URL using VirtualHost configuration in Apache using mod_rewrite without changing user browser URL.

i.e if someone access `grafana.test.lan:80` they should redirect to `http://grafana.test.lan:3000` without user knowledge or URL change.

This is my configuration file :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module "/etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so"

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName grafana.test.lan
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://grafana.test.lan:3000/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

any idea how I can do that? I am configuring it on Centos 7.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 way to do it:

#### 1. Using mod_proxy

To enable proxy mod, you have to send those commands in bash:

```
a2enmod proxy
ad2enmod proxy_http
```

Then by changing your web configuration like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName grafana.test.lan
ProxyPass / http://grafana.test.lan:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /  http://grafana.test.lan:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Official links: [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), [mod_proxy_http](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html)

#### 2. Using mod_rewrite

By changing your web configuration like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName grafana.test.lan
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://grafana.test.lan:3000/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Official link: [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Using the `P` flag on the `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) also uses mod_proxy.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with a rewrite. You need to use a reverse proxy between the users of the site and the server that's serving up on port 3000. Details are left as an exercise for the author.

Comment: Can you you please explain how can i do that in reverse proxy. i Am new to it.